# SSAS Hierachies duplicates when browsing

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimensional-modeling

The dimensions in the cube are giving us duplicates, there is no error while processing the cube, but when the cube is browsed we could see duplicates.

There is a hierarchy in our dimension, the hierarchy is built like `Country -- State -- Area`.

In the DB, the dimension data looks something like below.

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| Country |   State    |  Subarea  |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| India   | Karnataka  | Bangalore |
| India   | Telangana  | Hyderabad |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Now, when the cube is browsed with the attribute Country, we see 2 members under country as "India", when measure is selected against the attribute, the sales are shattered between these 2 values.

Can we do any work around to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That behaviour is dependent on your `KeyColumns` setting.

Given a cube with these 2 named queries in the `datasource view`

Cities:

```
SELECT        1 AS id, 'India' AS country, 'Calcutta' AS city
UNION
SELECT        2 AS id, 'India' AS country, 'Bangalore' AS city
```

Sales:

```
SELECT        1 AS city, 5 AS salesamount
UNION
SELECT        2 AS city, 5 AS salesamount
```

A dimension based on cities, linked to the Sales table on the  `sales.city->cities.id` relation that looks like this, using the id column as `KeyColumns`:

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

However, if I change the `KeyColumn` property to `country` for that attribute like this:

[image]

The result is all sales are reported under one single country:

[image]

I agree [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174919.aspx) is a bit terse:

> Contains the column or columns that represent the key for the
>   attribute, which is the column in the underlying relational table in
>   the data source view **to which the attribute is bound**. The value of
>   this column for each member is displayed to users unless a value is
>   specified for the NameColumn property.

Where you should interpret it as "there is one separate attribute member for each distinct value in the key column, even if the displayed value is the same"

Do note however that changing the key column might require you to change the `NameColumn` and the `OrderBy` properties.

Also, `KeyColumns` can be comprised of multiple columns acting as a unique key instead of a single key like in my example.

Sometimes when it's too risky for existing reports to change the structure already in place it might be a good option to add an extra attribute.